# AJAX Showing result a few seconds only then gone

Tags: javascript, ajax

```js
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
  return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

include 'connect.php';
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
}

$rs=mysql_query("select * from webuser where FirstName LIKE '%".$q."%' or MiddleName LIKE '%".$q."%' or LastName LIKE '%".$q."%' or address LIKE '%".$q."%' or contactno LIKE '%".$q."%'
    or department LIKE '%".$q."%' or position LIKE '%".$q."%' or username LIKE '%".$q."%'",$con);
if(!$rs) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
 echo '<script>alert(mysql_error())</script>';
}
else{
   //code to print here
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have a problem with my code, ajax shows the result but in just a second or less then disappear. Tried searching, nothing found. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SHOW.YOUR.CODE() !

Comment: That's my code, im sorry. Haha

Comment: Your showUser is broken. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use jQuery for that?

Comment: one thing that will help you to debug it is to add console log to the onreadystatechange handler. Just to see, how many times it is called and with what.

Comment: What is the problem with my show user sir alexey